# How to prove convergence or divergence of a serie with exponential expressions

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was requested to prove whether

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^{2n+1}}{n^n} $$

converges or diverges. I have tried different approaches; the ratio test did not work, nor I could find a useful comparison for the sequence. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have tried now the following approach:

$$a_n=\frac{5^{2n+1}}{n^n}=\frac{(5^2)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{n^n}=\frac{25^n*5}{n^n}=(\frac{25}{n})^n*5$$

Therefore

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^{2n+1}}{n^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{25}{n})^n*5 =5 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{25}{n})^n$$

Applying the root test, we see that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{(\frac{25}{n})^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{25}{n}=0<1$$

and then the serie converges. Is this correct?

Comment: Try the ratio test again.  Recall that $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\to\frac1e$

Comment: Your application of the root test is correct.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Fun fact, this series converges to $125\int_0^1 x^{-25 x} dx$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream

Comment: How beautiful that is! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**hint:** $n^n > 26^n, n \ge 27$.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the ratio test
$$a_n=\frac{5^{2n+1}}{n^n}\implies \log(a_n)=(2n+1)\log(5)-n\log(n)$$
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=n \log (n)-(n+1) \log (n+1)+2\log (5)$$ Now, using Taylor expansion
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=(2\log(5)-1)-\log \left({n}\right)-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{6
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)}=\frac{25}{e n}-\frac{25}{2 e n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$